# jQuery .ajax handling errors

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have setup my ajax request like

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.html',
    datatype: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).appendTo('body');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, e) {
        alert('An error occured: ' + status);
    }
});
```

when i trigger an error by specifying a non existent url, i find that status is always null. i tried `xhr.statusText`, `xhr.responseText`, `xhr.status` all returns nothing also. how can i get an error message?

when i try `alert(e)` i get

> [Exception... "Access to restricted
>   URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult:
>   "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)" 
>   location:
>   "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
>   Line: 130"]

but i want something more like page not found. why isit giving me access restricted? and why is status, xhr.statusText etc all null?

## UPDATE

it works online but not on localhost, maybe its just some configuration thing

Comment: I have tried `xhr.statusText` and it gives me `NOT FOUND`, on non-existing page... try it, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9yg6N/)

Answer (score 1):

Is this a cross-domain request? Browsers forbid cross-domain requests using the XmlHttpRequest AJAX technique. The request will not be processed and therefore the target server will not even know about the request, let alone get a chance to return a status code.

Comment: no i am on localhost. from test.html requesting ajax.html (success) or a non existent page eg. ajax2.html

Answer (score 0):

I just tried that on my system and when I point to a non-existing URL, `status` is set to `error` for me with no problem. However, it should be noted that you should configure your app on the server-side to send a 404 error when it receives a request for a non-existing page.

Comment: when i go to the non existant page in the browser, i get 404 error.